# Improve performance of Angular4 Application?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, page-load-time

**Scenario :**

- Using server side rendering by Angular Universal.
- My application take more than 10 seconds to load.

  And in the first time, it take more than 15 seconds to load.

**Tried Cases :**

- I am already doing minification, gzip etc.

**Todo :**

- I want to decrease it under 5 seconds.

  Is this performance issue because of angular universal?
  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the download size on initial page load . Did you try lazy loading , not sure if it makes sense for universal

Comment: read https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist

Comment: It can be a lot, maybe you are not using AOT and production builds? Anyway, it is not because of Angular Universal, I've done the same and it's pretty fast.